# Elasticsearch and Lucene document limit

Tags: elasticsearch

Document count in our elasticsearch installation from stats api shows about 700 million when the actual document count is about 27 million from the count api. We understand that this difference is from nested documents count - stats api shows all.

In Lucene documentation, we read that there is 2 billion hard document count limit for a shard. Should I worry that elasticsearch is about to hit the document limit? Or should I monitor the data from the count api?

Comment: Maybe you should consider splitting your data into more indexes.
For example, if you are storing time-based data, you can create daily indexes.

Comment: Actually we do not directly control the index, we depend on apache usergrid for index control.

Comment: Activating ILM may be a good choice to select!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is limit to the number of docs per shard of 2 billion, which is a hard lucene limit.

There is a maximum number of documents you can have in a single Lucene index.  As of [LUCENE-5843](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-5843), the limit is `2,147,483,519` (= Integer.MAX_VALUE - 128) documents.

You should consider scaling horizontally.