# Max number of records in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

May I know what is the number of records can I insert into Elasticsearch index? I have a 800k records, and tried to query _count for the particular index, I will get 100k records only. I inserted the records by using Java, RestHighLevelClient. May I check whether is there any max number of records that can be put inside the index? If yes, there is a limit, may I ask what can I do to workaround?

Comment: Theoretically there is no limit. This limit will be dependent on the storage size. You can grow the cluster by adding nodes dynamically without any downtime.

Comment: @OpsterESNinjaNishant this is not true, please refer my answer for more detail. and just adding more nodes will not be useful, until you increase the primary shards.

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja Yes I agree that there is per shard limit but it totally depends on the design that whether there will be a limit to the number of documents in elasticsearch (not shard). For e.g. consider time-based index design where I can keep on increasing indexes (eventually shards) and theoretically it becomes that there is no limit to the number of documents provided storage is available. Yes I agree my comment lacked this information and your answer and links clarifies more about it.

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja Also by adding node I was emphasising on how storage can be increased without downtime.

Comment: @OpsterESNinjaNishant no issues, I got your intent :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every Elasticsearch index made up of one or more shards which are internally Lucene index which has a hard limit of ~2 billion(precisely equal to INT_MAX value-128) on maximum no of the document as explained in [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-max-number-of-documents-for-one-index/26578/2?u=amitmbm) link and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41020169/4039431) link.

If you want to scale and store more than 2 billion documents, then increase the no of primary shards of your index, default is one primary shard from Elasticsearch 7.X. Please note that changing primary shards requires re-indexing, so plan optimal no of primary shards in advance.

Comment: I see.. I have only 800k of records, by right, it didn't exceed the limit. I think I will have to check what happened to my java program. Thanks for your advise.